# Open file in a new window using javascript

Tags: c#, javascript

I was checking compatibility of my application with different browsers, and am having this issue where a few browsers wont open a form in a new window.

Script I am using to do so:

```
string theScript= "<script>window.open('" + fileLocation + "','_blank','height=400,width=400,scrollbars=Yes,resizable=Yes')</script>";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "blah", theScript, false);
```

Is there a way to resolve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: did u try to write a function and just call it ? "openNewWindow(fileLocation)"

Comment: @Mennan, that will make no difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pop Up Blockers will block that type of window. That would be why it will not show up since there is no user action that causes it to open.

**How to resolve?**

- Have people disable the pop up blocker for your domain.
- Or open up the pop up in the client and have the server redirect it to the right location

Comment: firefox(using version 16) downloads the file instead of showing the new window. 

File is written using:

        Byte[] buffer = client.DownloadData(path);
        if (buffer != null)
        {
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"; //using pdf files only
            
            Response.AddHeader("content-length", buffer.Length.ToString());
            Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
        }

Answer (score 0):

You can detect whether popup is blocked or not and give user an option to make changes to his browser:

```
var pop = window.open("about:blank", "alert_window", "height=150,width=150");

// Detect pop blocker
setTimeout(function() {
if(!pop || pop.closed || pop.closed == "undefined" || pop == "undefined" || parseInt(pop.innerWidth) == 0 || pop.document.documentElement.clientWidth != 150 || pop.document.documentElement.clientHeight != 150){
pop && pop.close();
alert("Popups must be enabled.");
}else{
alert("Popups is enabled.");
pop && pop.close();
}}, 1000);
```